# Discord Bot-Cool or Not Command

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

```
 if (message.content.startsWith (prefix + "sop")) {
    number = 3;
    imageNumber = Math.floor (Math.random() * number) + 1;
    message.channel.send ({files: ["./coolornot/" + imageNumber + ".png"]}) 
    + message.channel.send("Is this Image cool or not?")

    if (message.content == (prefix + "cool")) {
      message.reply ("thinks this Image is cool")
    }
```

The first if function works but the other part doesn't work. Basically I want that the bot responds "%user% thinks this Image is cool" if someone writes prefix + cool as a response to the previous command. Hope someone could help me

And if possible, if someone writes cool I want the bot to send the picture in that user's PMs. But this is not a must, just a Little addition

Comment: Place your second `if` outside the first one and reply with `message.reply(message.getAuthor() + " thinks this image is cool");` DISCLAIMER: `message.getAuthor()` might not return the username. I haven't used this lib for a long time, so be sure to test that.

Comment: The thing is, I somehow want the command to only work after this first command, prefix + sop, was written. And I just can't figure out how that works :c

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it's possible to fetch all messages of a channel. You could check if the first command was executed within a specific "range" of messages and execute the second one if that condidition is met.